# How to join multiple price tables by date range in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL, and I would need help appending tables by matching dates. I have 2 tables of stock prices (i.e. Com A, Com B) generated from mysql.

They are as followed (non-exhaustive):

```
Com A
Date                      Price 
2015-05-01 00:00:00.000   34.25
2015-05-02 00:00:00.000   35.20
2015-05-03 00:00:00.000   36.70 
2015-05-04 00:00:00.000   32.37
2015-05-05 00:00:00.000   32.40
2015-05-06 00:00:00.000   32.20  


Com B
Date                      Price 
2015-05-01 00:00:00.000   54.29
2015-05-02 00:00:00.000   54.50
2015-05-04 00:00:00.000   56.21
2015-05-05 00:00:00.000   56.70
2015-05-06 00:00:00.000   58.20
```

However, I would like to output SQL query result with the following 4 columns (i.e. date, Com A, Com B, Com A - Com B):

```
Date                      Com A   Com B  Com A - Com B
2015-05-01 00:00:00.000   34.25   54.29  20.04
2015-05-02 00:00:00.000   35.20   54.50  19.30
2015-05-03 00:00:00.000   36.70   NULL   36.70
2015-05-04 00:00:00.000   32.37   56.21  23.84
2015-05-05 00:00:00.000   32.40   56.70  24.30
2015-05-06 00:00:00.000   32.20   58.20  26.00
```

Note that the difference between Com A and Com B is in absolute values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need standart join operation with `ABS` function to check absolute value

```
select a.date,
       IFNULL(a.price, 0) as comA,
       IFNULL(b.price, 0) as comB,
       ABS(a.price - b.price) as ComA_ComB
from com_A a left join com_B b on a.date = b.date
```

Note that you can also use inner join on date, which will return a bit different result based on what you wish to get

Comment: Hi Hatik, thank you for your reply! Actually I would need more help with the concatenation of the 2 tables, meaning to also output Date, Com A, Com B and ComA_ComB.

Comment: @JeffersonLow, hello, I don't get what you mean by outputing Date, could you please provide more explanation, or may be edit your question with desired result

Comment: hope this would make things clearer! I have edited the question.

Comment: @JeffersonLow did you run the query I provided? what was in the first column

Comment: RIGHT! It works, apologies! ): But thank you so much for explaining to me  (: